# react-redux dispatch undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

In my App.js :

```
const initialAppState = {
  nums: {},
};
const reducer = (state = initialAppState, action) => {
  if (
    action.a === undefined ||
    action.b === undefined ||
    action.c === undefined
  ) {
    return state;
  }
  if (state.nums[action.a][action.b] === undefined) {
    state.nums[action.a][action.b] = {};
  }
  return {
    nums: (state.nums[action.a][action.b] =
      action.c),
  };
};

const store = createStore(reducer);
```

Then passed it with **Provider**.
When in my Test.js I'm trying to change the value it give me error :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    nums: state.nums,
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    add: (a, b, c) =>
      dispatch({a: a, b: b, c: c}),
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(Test);
```

And the Test functional component looks like this :

```
function Test({nums, dispatch})
...
function add(data, count) {
    dispatch.add('1','2','3');
  }
```

It give me error saying :  **`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dispatch.add')`**

Shouldn't it recognize dispatch as dispatch is Test's parameter, and add is another function of that functional component ?

Comment: Why're you using `dispatch` ? if your action creator is firing a single action ... just return an object in this form `{ type: ACTION_TYPE, payload: {...} }`

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli, can you please tell how should I call the add method for redux ??

Comment: I recommend you follow a complete tutorial on youtube or udemy .... cause redux is kind of advanced topic ... and it's like a puzzle, if one piece is not there, the whole thing will not work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you organize your code. Try to move actions and reducers into separate files like actions.js, reducers.js.

REDUCER NEED SOME FIXES:

- In your example of reducer in the last return you are trying to **mutate state**.
- Also as you can see in your second `if` there are no `return`.

---

### PROPOSAL OF ACTIONS AND REDUCERS SEPARATION

Inside your `App.js` you will createStore:

```
//App.js
import { reducer } from "./reducers"

const store = createStore(reducer);
<Provider store={ store }>
 ...
</Provider>
```

Now let's do `actions.js` file:

```
//actions.js
export const ADD_ACTION='ADD_ACTION' // action type

export function addAction(data) {
 return { type: ADD_ACTION, data }
}
```

In reducers you'll move part of code from your `App.js`. I recommend you to use **switch** inside your reducer like that:

```
//reducers.js
import { ADD_ACTION } from "./actions";

const initialAppState = {
  nums: {},
};

export const reducer = (state = initialAppState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_ACTION:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { nums: action.data });
    default:
      return state
   }
};
```

As you can see one of the ADD_ACTION is returning new object with updated `nums` value. This is because one of the essential Redux rules is ["Do not mutate state"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state).

Now, let's try our action in Test.js. First import `addAction` from `actions.js`. Then call `dispatch` with `addAction` as an argument.

```
//Test.js functional component version
import { addAction } from "./actions";

function Test({dispatch}) {
  ...
  function add(data, count) {
    dispatch(addAction(data));
  }
}

export default connect(null, null)(Test);
```

Component receives `dispatch` from connect. Connect has (null, null) because in this case we are not using mapStateToProps, nor mapDispatchToProps.

**Extra tip**: For class component you'll use action in a little bit different way.

```
//Test.js Class component version
import React from 'react';
import { addAction } from "./actions";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TestClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <button onClick={() => this.props.addAction(2)}>Action</button>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ({
 addAction
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TestClass);
```

In class component example you'll call action with value `2` when onClick event fires.

Working sandbox example: [react-redux example](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-davinci-ikw7c?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: i put a `console.debug` just before `return { type: ADD_ACTION, data }`, and here but gets logged... but before `export const reducer = (state = initialAppState, action) => {` I tried a `console.debug(action)` **it shows nothing and it's never gets called...**

Comment: There was problem with Test.js. I have fixed it. Now it is quite similar to your style because we call `dispatch` inside `add` function. I have added also an example how you can call an action inside class component.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not `dispatch.add()` its `props.add()`

```js
// add comes in as a prop. that’s why it’s called map dispatch to props.
function Test({nums, add: doAdd})
...
function add(data, count) {
    doAdd('1','2','3');
}
```